# Override block vendor/magento/module-review/Block/Adminhtml/Edit/Form.php to remove mandatory field Review

Tags: magento2, adminhtml

I created a module that modifies Magento_Review module in frontend (I removed the mandatory field Review detail).

Now I need to remove the same field (or at least make it optional – not mandatory) in Magento Admin (see image).

[image]

I’ve tried to override the block vendor/magento/module-review/Block/Adminhtml/Edit/Form.php and remove the mandatory field. But for some reason Magento won’t “display” the modified block.

What I am missing?

Thank you